# TypeError: keytar.addPassword is not a function on electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying to use keytar at my electron project, but I got this error:

> TypeError: keytar.addPassword is not a function

I saw the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keytar) but it seems that addPassword does not exist.

My main.js is:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const keytar = require('keytar');

const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;

const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let mainWindow;
let appIcon;

function createWindow() {
  keytar.addPassword('KeytarTest', 'AccountName', 'secret');
  const secret = keytar.getPassword('KeytarTest', 'AccountName');
  console.log(secret);
  const { width, height } = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width, height });

  mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);

  const contents = mainWindow.webContents;

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: this has nothing to do with electron, create an issue in the repo of that package

Comment: according to the documentation there is no `addPassword` , but there is `setPassword` try it out and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I saw the docs but it seems that addPassword does not exist.

Yes, that's right. The function addPassword does not **exist** and that's why you're getting this TypeError.

In general, this has nothing to do with Electron, because the keytar package just does not provide the function you were trying to call.

If a function is not mentioned in the docs, it's most likely to not exist.

Comment: @avisk OP was not sure why they were receiving the error and this answer gives the reason. The question does not ask how to achieve what OP was trying to do (and does not include a description of the problem they're trying to solve). Thus, this is the only real answer I could give at the time since everything else would be speculation. However, please feel free to add an answer of our own!

Comment: Didn't OP already figure that out? I assumed they were looking for an alternative function to use in the answer. For future reference, `setPassword` should be used instead of `addPassword`: https://openbase.com/js/keytar/documentation#setpasswordservice-account-password